# how to set font size of toolbar in ionic

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am using toolbar I am able to make toolbar .But I need to customise that toolbar .Actually I am trying to set different **font size** as default in button and I need to give different width of buttons as default .

I have this **button bar**

```
  <div class="button-bar">
      <a class="button button-small" ng-click="handlerButtonClick('a')" ng-class="{'button_active':activeContentArea==='a'}">abc</a>
      <a class="button button-small" ng-click="handlerButtonClick('r')" ng-class="{'button_active':activeContentArea==='r'}">rnf </a>
      <a class="button button-small" ng-click="handlerButtonClick('d')" ng-class="{'button_active':activeContentArea==='d'}">dfff</a>
      <a class="button button-small" ng-click="handlerButtonClick('n')" ng-class="{'button_active':activeContentArea==='n'}">ndsdf</a>
    </div>
```

I need to override the default behaviour mean override fontsize of text  and width of buttons 
here is my plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/eGaPwUdPgknwDnozMJWU?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to modify font-size and width of bar buttons

```
.button-bar > .button {
    flex: none; /* in order to modify width */
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/4d9X2icZJicGdjezR6WG?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks..!! got solution